# Spring Boot Microservices Saga example

Tags: microservices, cqrs, saga

I am looking to learn the **Spring Boot Microservices Saga** based project. I went through web and found many theoretical links like https://www.baeldung.com/cs/saga-pattern-microservices and https://microservices.io/patterns/data/saga.html, but I don't find the simple source code witch depicts the working code.

Can anyone please share the link to source code which is working POC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following if it helps:
https://github.com/berndruecker/trip-booking-saga-java

Although I would suggest you using the [Axon](https://axoniq.io/) framework. It is designed for an event-driven system. You can easily find many examples related to the saga in axon as well. May be something like this:   https://github.com/dashsaurabh/saga-pattern-axon-spring-boot-sample